# Can't find right query for MongoDB using mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have been trying to get a list of the newest(According to its EstablishedDate) Pharmacy that has each medicine.

**Take this output as a result of the following array of documents as a sample:**

> **Output:**
>    Medicine : MedA ,  Pharmacy : a
>    Medicine : MedB ,  Pharmacy : b
>    Medicine : MedC ,  Pharmacy : b
>    Medicine : MedD ,  Pharmacy : a

```
[
  {
    "Pharmacy": "a",
    "EstablishedDate": ISODate("2006-10-12"),
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedA",
        "Quantity": 55
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 34
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedD",
        "Quantity": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Pharmacy": "b",
    "EstablishedDate": ISODate("2015-2-2"),
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 60
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedC",
        "Quantity": 34
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: it's projection in aggregation operation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/  otherwise You can just do with nodejs map result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Answer for all medicines with respective pharmacies

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Medicine"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "Medicine": "$Medicine.MedName",
      "Pharmacy": "$Pharmacy"
    }
  }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "Medicine": "MedA",
    "Pharmacy": "a"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedB",
    "Pharmacy": "a"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedD",
    "Pharmacy": "a"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedB",
    "Pharmacy": "b"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedC",
    "Pharmacy": "b"
  }
]
```

Refer [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eEOMpm62Wda) and run the script

2.All Medicine with latest Pharmacies

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Medicine"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      EstablishedDate: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Medicine.MedName",
      Pharmacy: {
        $first: "$Pharmacy"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "Medicine": "$_id",
      "Pharmacy": "$Pharmacy"
    }
  }
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "Medicine": "MedA",
    "Pharmacy": "a"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedC",
    "Pharmacy": "b"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedD",
    "Pharmacy": "a"
  },
  {
    "Medicine": "MedB",
    "Pharmacy": "b"
  }
]
```

Refer Respective [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U3VSKcUg6_6) and run the script

Comment: What would I need to do if I only wanted to show only the  **newest** pharmacy to have medicines, so for example MedB would only show pharmacy "b" since its **newer** than pharmacy "a"

Comment: i have updated my answer and approve the answer if you liked my efforts